# problem while injecting information into mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a social media app, so im currently injecting information from my data off my pc into my mongodb ,I just finished injecting the information of the posts of my app, now im currently trying to inject information of my users and keep getting hit with an error preventing me from injecting my users information in vscode it looks like this

```
Server Port: 3001
/Users/user/Documents/Fullstack web development/server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/common.js:309
            return callback(new MongoBulkWriteError(err, new BulkWriteResult(bulkOperation.s.bulkResult)));
                            ^

MongoBulkWriteError: connection 3 to 35.169.70.52:27017 closed
    at resultHandler (/Users/user/Documents/Fullstack web development/server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/common.js:309:29)
    at /Users/user/Documents/Fullstack web development/server/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:292:66
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  connectionGeneration: 1,
  writeErrors: [],
  result: BulkWriteResult {
```

I haven't tried anything's can't just understand what is wrong exactly

Comment: The part of the error you included indicates the connection to the database closed.  Does the rest of the error message provide any more information?

Comment: it just  printed out the information I was trying to inject onto the terminal

Comment: Perhaps check the server log to see if it tells you why the connection closed?